# Finding the arc length of a curve on the upper half-plane.

Tags: differential-geometry

I'm trying the following question and not getting anywhere.

Define the first fundamental form on the upper half-plane $U = \{(u,v)\in\mathbb{R}^2 | v >0\}$ by

$$E(u,v):=\frac{1}{v^2},\space F(u,v):=0,\space G(u,v):=\frac{1}{v^2}.$$

Consider the curve $\alpha_{v_0} \subset  U$ defined as $\alpha_{v_0}(t) = (t,v_0)$ where $t\in(0,1)$ and $v_0>0$ a constant. Find the arc length $l(\alpha_{v_0})$ of the curve $\alpha_{v_0}(t)$. Determine $l(\alpha_{v_0})$ as $v_0 \rightarrow  \infty$.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Cheers.

Comment: Make some effort here. Write down the integral that computes the arclength. Where are you having problems finishing?

Comment: Okay so far I've used the general formula $L = \int \sqrt{u'^2E(\alpha_{v0}(t)) + u'v'F(\alpha_{v0}(t)) + v'^2G(\alpha_{v0}(t))} dt$ where $E,F.G$ are the coefficients of the fundamental form in the question. Since $v_0$ is a constant we have that $v' = 0$ and also $u' = t' = 1$. With $t \in (0,1)$ we have $L = \int_{t=0}^{t=1} \sqrt{E(\alpha_{v0}(t))} dt = \int_{t=0}^{t=1} \sqrt{\frac{1}{v_0^2}} dt = \int_{t=0}^{t=1} \frac{1}{v_0} dt = \frac{1}{v_0} \rightarrow 0$ as $v_0 \rightarrow \infty$. Is this on the rigts lines.

Comment: Yes, this is perfect.

Comment: Okay brilliant. Thanks for verifying.